# Differences between Watir Webdriver in Ruby and Splinter in Python for browser test automation?

Tags: python, ruby, watir, browser-automation, splinter

I have already used Ruby and Watir Webdriver for browser automation. It has many positive aspects but as well as having their library, webdriver update delay and some minor issues.

What are the differences between Splinter in Python language with them. Like- in their documentation Splinter gives Chrome and Firefox support whereas Watir Webdriver gives IE support as well. What are more major differences?

Comment: From Splinter's documentation, it sounds like it is built on Selenium (using the Python bindings). Ultimately, that means it will have the same Webdriver issues as Watir, which is also built on Selenium.